# Update Installation: How to save the app.config?

Tags: c#, installation, windows-installer, orca

I have a huge problem:

I have an old application App1.0.exe. With this Application there is a file called App1.0.exe.config (the App config). Now i made the Version 2.0, with the new Version now there are different Appsettings in the Appconfig. My question is: How i can save the old Appconfig when make an Update Installation?

This try's to solve the problem have failed:

-Read out the old config with BeforeInstall event, save to the context parameters and write in the new config in an Afterinstall event. - The BeforeInstall read out the new config (the old one is deleted).
-Don't copy the new Appconfig but Copy a File with an different name e.g. AppConfigUpdate.config who include the new appconfig. In an afterinstall Event i save the old Config with an File.Move(). Now whe have:

-Appconfig.exe.config_Original

-AppconfigUpdate.config

Than i read out the .config_Original and write the parameter in the AppConfigUpdate.config and rename this to Appconfig.exe.config

My problem is that there is a standard action in msi that execute after execute my custom actions called: RemoveExistingProducts. So now when i Debugg the installer i can see at the end of my customaction there is the old configuration .config_original and the new configuration .config with the right params from the old configuration. But after my custom action the installation delete the the .config and only the .config_original is remaining.

I think that the RemoveExistingProducts delete all files that were not delivered with the update package. But i can't deliver the .config because than it's overwrite the original config and all params are lost.

I'm now working over 3 day's on this problem and i really need your help. I run out of ideas how to solve this problem, maby anyone of you had some similar problem?

Sorry for my bad english.
best regards

Comment: Why do you need to save the old App.config at all? The values in there shouldn't be changed in any way since you deployed V1 so you should excatly know whats in there, because all settings changed by the user is saved in the user.config under AppData...

Comment: Why not? If the user installed v1 why he need to configure v2 new when there the same settings as in v1? Yes i know i shouldn't change the settings, it was a huge mistake :(. But the problem is: it's happend and now i'm try to fix this problem. The Problem is there some paths to other programms e.g. so they can be different

Answer (score 2):

The correct approach would be to use two custom actions to back-up and restore your old config file. The back-up custom action would be executed before RemoveExistingProducts action. The restore custom action would be executed after InstallFiles. Some simple script custom action would do the job.

For more details on custom actions please see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368066(VS.85).aspx

Unfortunately Visual Studio setup doesn't have a good scheduling support custom actions. You will have to use another free or commercial msi authoring tool.

Comment: This idea is great, but the problem is: When i add the config to the output it overwrite the new Config before i can save the old. If i call the config update.exe.config save the old and rename the update to exe.config: The msi installer deinstall the old config

Comment: Instead of renaming the config file, you should move it to another location, Temp folder for example. Also be sure to schedule the back-up custom action before RemoveExistingProducts.

Comment: No that's the problem. I save the old Configuration File Appconfig.exe.config with renaming it to Appconfig.exe.config_original than i rename the AppconfigUPDATE.exe.config to Appconfig.exe.config so i have .exe.config and .exe.config_original. When my Custom Action end both config are there, i can see it when i debugg the installation. But after my Custom Action the Standart Action RemoveExistingProducts start i think and delete the Appconfig.exe.config (the new configuration) because i don't delivered this Appconfig.exe.config file with the new Installation. Can't solve this

Comment: Your approach is too complicated. Just back-up the files and let the installation of the new package overwrite it. Then restore it.

Comment: Yes but how can i do this in a one-file installation? That's all i wan't but i can't :(. And i can't believe that there is no way to save the old app-config in a msi installation by a microsoft function. I saw so often that basic functions are saved in the app config, and if the user or the programm changed this so why you can't apply the old configuration settings.

Comment: The files gets deleted because RemoveExinstingProducts uninstalls the older version of the MSI. Since your updated file has the same name as the file from the original MSI it gets removed. When updating the file you should not rename it to  Appconfig.exe.config right away. Schedule another custom action after InstallFiles which will rename the file.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's possible to work around the behaviour of the installer?

Rather than re-write the configuration during installation, what could work is for your application to test *on startup* whether the configuration is of the "Version 1" format. If so, it performs the update at that point.

There's (old, but valid) details on updating app.config here: http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/articles/64871.aspx .

Comment: This sounds good but i hoped to fix this problem with the new installer. Maby i find a soulution, else i will fix this problem on your way. thanks